# If $e^{ei\pi}$ turns out to be transcendent, can it be proved that $e^e$ is also?

Tags: transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

We know that $e^e$ is not proved to be transcendent, so neither is the number $e^{ei\pi}$.

> If $e^{ei\pi}$ turns out to be transcendent, can it be proved that $e^e$ is also?

Comment: Here's the issue with this question: suppose that $e^e$ is transcendental (which seems rather likely). How can you show that $e^e$ can't be proven to be transcendental with the knowledge that $e^{ei\pi}$ is transcendental?

Comment: But how can you prove that $e^{ei\pi}$ is transcendental?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4077214 Why are you also interested in this subject?